# What is the purpose of git stash when you can just make a new commit?

Tags: git

I'm learning about git stash [here](http://www.gitguys.com/topics/temporarily-stashing-your-work/) but don't understand the purpose of it when you can just make a commit before switching to other branches and work. Is it just more convenient? Or more clean to not have to add an additional entry to your commit log just because you had to switch to another branch to do something really quick?

Also, when you use `git stash pop` does it automatically jump you back to the branch that you stashed? What if I wanted to make a different stash for each branch?

Comment: One clever alternative to using `git stash` is to simply make a commit, and then amend the commit later when you have reached a logical breaking point.  All the power of `git stash` without leaving a weird aftertaste in your mouth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct that you can just commit (and then come back and `git reset --soft` to un-commit, later), and I do that sometimes when rebasing.

> Also, when you use `git stash pop` does it automatically jump you back to the branch that you stashed? What if I wanted to make a different stash for each branch?

It does not.  (I see someone has already mentioned the `stash@{N}` notation so I will leave that out of this answer, except to add that this uses Git's reflogs.)  Applying the stash is mostly, though not entirely, like using `git show` or `git log -p` to convert a commit to a patch, then applying the patch with `git apply`.

A stash is stored as two or three<sup>1</sup> commits that are not on any branch.  I like to call these commits a "stash bag", for several reasons, one of which is that the bag hangs off the specific commit that was current when you made the stash.

If we draw a series of ordinary (non-merge) commits as a line of nodes `o` each of which points to its parent, and then draw in the branch name as a pointer identifying the tip commit of the branch, we get a nice compact representation of part of the commit graph:

```
... <- o <-o <- o   <-- branch
```

Normally we just leave out the internal arrows since we know each commit points to its parent:

```
...--o--o--o   <-- branch
```

Making a stash at this point hangs two<sup>2</sup> commits off the tip commit.  One of these, the one I label `i`, is the *index* state (what you have `git add`ed), and the other, `w`, is the *work-tree* state (all tracked files in the work-tree that you could have `git add`ed):

```
...--o--o--o   <-- branch
           |\
           i-w <-- stash
```

This stash bag just hangs on there, dangling away cheerfully, and is found via the special `stash` reference.  Because it *is* found via `stash`, if you run `git log --all` or `gitk --all` or similar, you will see it.

If you then *rebase* your branch, Git does this by copying the commits on the branch, back to whatever point.  That is, the "before" graph is more accurately drawn like this:

```
...--o--o--o--o--o--o  <-- feature
      \
       \
        \
         o--o--o       <-- branch
               |\
               i-w     <-- stash
```

Rebasing `branch` on `feature` makes new copies of the old commits, and moves the label:

```
...--o--o--o--o--o--o  <-- feature
      \              \
       \              o--o--o   <-- branch
        \
         o--o--o       [abandoned: previous branch]
               |\
               i-w     <-- stash
```

Note that if you run `git log --all` or `gitk --all`, you would normally no longer see your original branch and its three commits, but since `stash` is still hanging out there pointing to `w`, what now shows up is not only the stash but also the original three commits.

Running `git stash pop`—I actually suggest sticking with `git stash apply`<sup>3</sup> until you are really comfortable with stashes and Git in general, since `apply` gives you a chance to change your mind, but let's go ahead and consider `pop`—makes Git apply the stash to your new current commit (probably the new tip of the copied `branch`) and then drop the `stash` reference:

```
...--o--o--o--o--o--o  <-- feature
      \              \
       \              o--o--o   <-- branch
        \
         o--o--o       [abandoned: previous branch]
               |\
               i-w     [abandoned]
```

and *now* all those old commits, along with the stash, no longer show up.

If you make a regular commit instead of a stash, and then rebase, the rebase copies the regular commit.  Using `git reset --soft` to discard it, abandons it the same way you would have abandoned the stash by popping, so ultimately these two do pretty much the same thing (except that any changes you need to make because of the `rebase` happen during the `rebase` step, rather than the `git stash apply && git stash drop` step).

Note that applying the stash is done in two steps, or three if there are three commits: first Git applies the index changes, then it applies the work-tree changes (and untracked files if needed).  If you use the `--index` flag when applying, Git attempts to restore the changes to staged and not-staged, exactly as they were when you did the `git stash save` to create the stash-bag.  Otherwise it just kind of mushes them together into the work-tree.

(This mushing-together is another reason to use `git stash apply` separately, since you can reset them away and `git stash apply --index` if that's what you *meant* to do ... but only if you have not dropped the stash yet.)

---

<sup>1</sup>The stash script makes the third commit if you use `-u` or `-a` to stash unstaged or all files.  In this case, `stash` still points to commit `w`, but `w` has a third parent commit that contains these extra files.  This third commit has no parent of its own, unlike the `i` commit, which has the same parent as `w`.  In other words, the stash bag still hangs off the same commit as always, but now it has one extra root commit as a third parent, which is hard to describe at all.

<sup>2</sup>Or three, as in the previous footnote.

<sup>3</sup>Using `git stash pop` simply runs `git stash apply && git stash drop`, though slightly more efficiently as it is all done within one script, rather than as two separate commands.  If the `apply` fails entirely, the `drop` does not happen, but if the `apply` works and goes wrong, the `drop` *does* happen.  So, if you discover that the apply produced a mess, and you would like to go back and convert it to a `git stash save` later, it's too late.

The `git stash branch` code converts the stash to a new branch.  If the commit that the stash-bag hung from has been abandoned, this effectively resurrects that commit (and all its parents) under the new branch name.

Answer (score 3):

If you work alone in your project and you don't mind the dirty log, then go ahead and commit.

But if you work in a team, then committing a non-working or a non-compiling change will be frown upon. Sure, you could commit and not push it, but nevertheless it is a bad habit: it messes with all kinds of workflows, merge/rebase conflicts, bisects, etc.

If you stash your changes, then you bother nobody.

About the branch question: no, when you `git stash pop` you apply the stash in the current branch, no matter the branch where you stashed it. You can make as many stashes as you want, they just keep on stacking and you can pop anyone, not just in reverse order, with `git stash pop stash@{N}`. (But see `git stash branch` for an alternative).

If you feel that you need a different stash list for each branch, then you will probably be better using private branches that follow the public ones.

Answer (score 3):

The official git documentation [lists a few situations](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-stash.html)(look in the examples section) in which you may want to use `git stash`. Like you said, it's mostly used for the convenience/speed it affords in certain situations as opposed to commiting.

`git stash pop` tries to apply the stashed changes on top of the current branch that you are currently on(on top of the current working tree state, to be precise).

The stash is created globally and not on a per-branch basis. You can, however, save a stash with a label corresponding to your branch using `git stash save <label>`.